# Updating adapter with AsyncTaskLoader in a regular (support) Fragment not updating ListView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-listfragment, android-loader

I'm having trouble using the `AsyncTaskLoader` callbacks to update an adapter in a regular `Fragment`. I'm using the fragment support library, version 19.1.0.

In my `onLoadFinished()` callback I simply do an `mAdapter.addAll(data)`. I used the debugger to verify that the callback is called and that all of the data is added to the adapter. The problem is that the list view simply won't update.

I've already tried `notifyDataSetChanged()` and `invalidateViews()` - no effect.

All examples or tutorials I've seen so far use a `ListFragment` or `ListActivity` without a custom layout;  I've tried this and it works fine. In particular, I've tried the sample program from [Android Design Patterns loader tutorial](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/09/tutorial-loader-loadermanager.html). Unfortunately, I can't use `ListFragment` because I'm using the [StickyListHeaders](https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) library (but even trying this with a regular `ListView` doesn't work).

I get the same results when modifying the [above sample program](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/AppListLoader) to use a `Fragment` instead of `ListFragment` by removing the `ListFragment`-specific method calls and inflating a custom view. The relevant code boils down to this:

```java
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    mAdapter = new AppListAdapter(getActivity());
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_ID, null, this);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView (LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, container, false);
    ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<List<AppEntry>> loader, List<AppEntry> data) {
    mAdapter.setData(data);
}
```

As I said before, the adapter gets updated but the list view simply won't redraw, even if you add in notifyDataSetChanged and call invalidateViews on the listView. I'm finding it hard to figure out what's going wrong here.

Comment: And what is your adapter code?

Comment: Indeed, we need to see your adapter code - if the views aren't updating, then the adapter is likely the culprit.

Comment: Just to clarify, I mean that the ListView remains blank, and none of the items in the adapter are shown. The code for the adapter used by the example above can be found [here](https://github.com/alexjlockwood/AppListLoader/blob/master/src/com/adp/loadercustom/AppListAdapter.java). The adapter code for the actual app I'm working on can be found [here](https://github.com/rutgersmobile/android-client/blob/master/app/src/main/java/edu/rutgers/css/Rutgers/model/SectionedListAdapter.java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was initializing the adapter in `onActivityCreated`, as it's called *after* `onCreateView` - so `setAdapter` was being passed a null value (and it doesn't complain about that). This wasn't a problem in the `ListFragment` and `ListActivity` implementations I'd looked at as you can use their `setListAdapter` method to associate the adapter with the list view, without keeping your own explicit reference to it. A silly mistake :\

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar problems before. The root of mine seemed to be not calling `notifyDataSetChanged` from the ui thread. Your problem may be similar, try:

```
yourContext.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

And let me know if it works for you.

Comment: The behavior doesn't change, the ListView still doesn't show anything. I believe the LoaderManager callbacks are supposed to be called on the UI thread.

Comment: Hmm, perhaps try putting most of your listview logic in the ui thread. Could you perhaps copy paste your adapter code into a question edit?